# Swift UITextField Class not showing edits

Tags: ios, swift, class

Here I am trying to make a modified textfield input with Swift and Xcode. As instructed i created a class that extends the `UITextField` and set the properties that I want to change, however when I build the app I only see the normal text input. I feel like I'm missing something when creating classes or not returning something properly, here is my code:

**First viewController:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var verificationInput: borderBottomTextField!
```

**borderBottomTextField Class:**

```
class borderBottomTextField: UITextField {


required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(borderBottomTextField.myFunc), for: UIControlEvents.editingDidBegin);
}

func myFunc() {
    //Border
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

    //Background
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.0)

    //Text
    self.textColor = UIColor.red
    self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `func myFunc()` will call when `borderBottomTextField` detect `editingDidBegin` event
2. `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` will call when you add your view via `xib`, when you adding subview via code you should implement `initWithFrame` method.

Could you show how you add `borderBottomTextField` to views hierarchy?

Comment: @KamilHarasimowicz : you should not ask for upvote as per so's guidelines!